# Can't add CSS on ERB file, Sinatra

Tags: html, css, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to add Twitter Bootstrap CSS to an ERB file and run with Sinatra, but CSS don't show up.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

my folder structure is the same in the code.

I've already tried `href="lib/...` and `href="../lib/...` and don't work

Any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should copy `bootstrap.min.css` in your Sinatra `public` directory. Then use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to include it in your page.

Comment: Thank you @riccardo-marotti! I tried to use /public/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css too, but didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: The contents of your `public` directory are statically served in the root of Sinatra app. You can create `bootstrap/css` directory in your `public` folder, and put `bootstrap.min.css` in it: this way you can use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`